# Can't login to phpmyadmin on my mac running Yosemite

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm running Yosemite 10.10.1
I'm running latest mysql 5.6.22. It's running in system prefs. I can access the database using mysql workbench.
I have set a root password and I can enter: mysql -u root -p and it works.
I am running latest Apache.
I am running MacOSX Server 4
I have setup phpmyadmin, deleted the config sample file.

Here is my phpmyadmin config file.

```
/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'mypassword';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

But I can't login to phpmyadmin.
I go to localhost/phpmyadmin or 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin and I get the login window.
When I enter root and my password, I get an error saying:
 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

It's driving me crazy!!!

mysql root password does work!

Thanks

Comment: Try using host '127.0.0.1' in the phpMyAdmin configuration instead of 'localhost'. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'm late to the party, but I solved the exact same error by using these commands in Terminal:

`sudo mkdir /var/mysql`

`sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock`

The socket was in the 'wrong' place, this effectively tells the system where it's location is. Hope this helps anyone in future!

Answer (score 1):

download fresh copy of PHPMyAdmin and copy it to document root, naming phpmyadmin and from terminal make directory like

```
mkdir ~/Sites/phpmyadmin/config
```

change permission

```
chmod o+w ~/Sites/phpmyadmin/config
```

And Setup phpmyadmin from

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/setup/
```

Comment: Already did all that. Downloaded the latest, renamed it, chomped it, set it up. That was all done correctly.